# How to mock S3 putObject() with user metadata?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mock-aws-s3

I need to mock AWS S3 when using putObject().

When calling the function I need to create the file with user metadata values.
I tried to find some code examples over the web, but I found only this base code:

```
var AWSMock = require('mock-aws-s3');
AWSMock.config.basePath = '/tmp/buckets/' // Can configure a basePath for your local buckets
var s3 = AWSMock.S3({
    params: { Bucket: 'example' }
});
s3.putObject({Key: 'sea/animal.json', Body: '{"is dog":false,"name":"otter","stringified object?":true}'}, function(err, data) {
    s3.listObjects({Prefix: 'sea'}, function (err, data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, it's not includes the user metadata map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the parameters you're passing to the `putObject()` function, include a `Metadata` key which contains key/value pairs of the metadata you want to store with the S3 object.

Example:

```js
s3.putObject({
    Key: 'sea/animal.json',
    Metadata: {
        MyKey: 'MyValue',
        MyKey2: 'MyValue2'
    },
    Body: '{"is dog":false,"name":"otter","stringified object?":true}'
}, function (err, data) { 
    // ...
});
```

See: [putObject - Class: AWS.S3 — AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property)